# intalling htk on ubuntu 12.04 inside bin directory

Tags: 12.04

I’m getting an error when trying to

```
$ sudo make all
```

the htk files during installation:

```
(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/bin/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from HShell.h:40,
                 from HGraf.c:54:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [HGraf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/bin/htk/HTKLib'
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1
```

this is the error I get, I had managed to read it, but didn’t know what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following development package (the one [providing](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=predefs.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) `bits/predefs.h`):

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Comment: then,...afta installing the libc6-dev...i installed the updates then rebooted the systen,.. and shortcuts where disabled,..menubar is lost,..even that bar at the top with a shutdown button..